# Use testing environment variables in PHPSpec

Tags: php, environment-variables, phpspec

I have a service that use `getenv` function to set some properties. The environment variables are set with a `symfony/dotenv` component.

```
class BrowshotConfiguration
{
    private $apiKey;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->instanceList = preg_split('/\D+/', getenv('BROWSHOT_INSTANCE_LIST'));
    }

    public function getInstanceId(int $index)
    {
        if ($this->instanceList) {
            return $this->instanceList[$index] ?? false;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I want to test that BrowshotConfiguration::getInstanceId retruns a proper value but I BROWSHOT_INSTANCE_LIST is empty so I do not get a real value.

How could I fill the BROWSHOT_INSTANCE_LIST for running tests with one values but use different value for production?

Comment: I mean `putenv`)

Comment: @u_mulder, you mean add the `putenv` into a phpspec `let` function in each test that should use environment variables?

Comment: I'm not familar with phpspec but my idea is to set your env-variable explicitly for your tests

Comment: It looks like a hack; however, it works when I did it.